# Issue with generating XML file from SQL Server using BCP

Tags: sql-server, bcp

I am trying to generate XML file from the view using BCP. View has around 21M records. When I try to generates XML, BCP generate empty file. I checked this process with around 4M records and it works fine.

Please refer below code:

```
DECLARE @bcpCommand VARCHAR(8000), @FileName VARCHAR(100) = 'Customer_20190830.xml';
SET @bcpCommand
    = 'bcp "SELECT CAST(''<?xml version=""1.0"" ?>'' AS VARCHAR(100)) + CAST((SELECT * FROM dbo.vw_CustomersFOR XML PATH (''Customer''), TYPE, ROOT(''Customers'')) AS VARCHAR(MAX));" queryout E:\Share\Customer\'
      + @FileName + ' -S -d Test-T -c';
PRINT @bcpCommand;
EXEC master..xp_cmdshell @bcpCommand;
```

Is there any upper limit to writing XML object from SQL Server? Is the any work around? I don't want to generate multiple files.

Comment: from microsofts documentation :The data file can contain a maximum of 2^63 - 1 rows. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/tools/bcp-utility?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: and according ot the same documentation you are missing the -x option for xml? I mean it looks like it is working for the smaller data set, so not sure if this applies

Comment: What happens if you dump results set into a table first then just select * from it in your bcp query?

Comment: What happens if you dump results set into a table first then just select * from it in your bcp query? - Same thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That loads the whole table into a nvarchar(max) and sends that to the client.  It's not an infinitely-scalable approach.

Here's how to stream arbitrary amounts of XML to a file using PowerShell:

```
# for xml query, not using the TYPE directive, for streaming large results
$sql = "select * from sys.objects for xml path, root('root')"
$fn = "c:\temp\output.xml"
$constr = "Server=localhost;Database=tempdb;integrated security=true"

$con = new-object System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection
$con.ConnectionString = $constr 
$con.Open()

$cmd = $con.CreateCommand()
$cmd.CommandTimeout = 0
$cmd.CommandText = $sql

$xr = $cmd.ExecuteXmlReader()
$fs = [System.IO.File]::OpenWrite($fn)
$xw = [System.Xml.XmlWriter]::Create($fs)

$xw.WriteNode($xr,$true)

$xw.Close()
$fs.Close()
$xr.Close()
$con.Close()
```

Comment: Exception calling "ExecuteXmlReader" with "0" argument(s): "An XML operation resulted an XML data type exceeding 2GB in size. Operation aborted."

Comment: Remove the `TYPE` directive from your `FOR XML` query.  You don't need to create an XML data type instance here, just stream the xml to the client.